# How do I rejoin the College of Winterhold if Ancano is hostile?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Whenever I walk into Winterhold, Ancano attacks me, and he's not supposed to.
How do I resolve this problem? Because it's making all of Skyrim attack me and I can't do anything anymore.

I've watched YouTube videos on how its supposed to go, but whenever I walk into Winterhold, Ancano just attacks me and I can't complete the mission as the Eye of Magnus is still closed?
I have tried to talk to Tolfdir to rejoin the college, but this can not be done.

Comment: Do you have the "Rejoining the College" quest?

Comment: Yes i do, but whenever i try to speak with tolfdir, it wont allow me

Comment: What do you mean "it won't allow me"? Is he hostile? Is the dialogue simply not there?

Comment: Are you playing on the PC or a console?

Comment: Console, Ps3. When he is not hostile, but when i press 'X' to talk to him, it just wont talk to him.

Comment: Too bad you are not using PC... it would so much easier when you can just use console commands to fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you've encountered a bug. The only way to fix the solution is to cast a calm spell on Ancano to stop combat, but only for a limited time. Then talk to Tolfdir to pay the College bounty and rejoin the College and do the quests.